# vuejs v-for only few elements from array, based on categories

Tags: vue.js

Ive got an array of elements, which I'm showing on page, using v-for:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
     <v-layout  row wrap v-for="offer in offers.slice((current_page-1)*5, current_page*5)">
        ...
    </v-layout>
  <v-container>
</template>

<script>
   export default{
      data(){
        offers: [array of offers here],
      }
   }
```

Now I decided to add categories and show only the offers with certain categories from array (data is like: `offer.speciality[1]` - category 1; `offer.speciality[2]` - category 2 etc...)

So I added the most simple v-show element, like this:

```
<v-layout  row wrap v-for="offer in offers.slice((current_page-1)*5, current_page*5)" 
v-show="checkArray(offer, speciality)">
```

and speciality variable (getting values from the select)

```
<script>
   export default{
      data(){
        offers: [array of offers here],
        speciality:''
      }
   }
```

where function checkArray is just checking if specialityID is the same that offer.speciality[i] and returning true or false to `v-show` element

```
    checkArray(offer, id){
        if (id)
        {
            for (var i in offer.specialities) {
                if (offer.specialities[i] == id)
                {
                  return true;
                  break;
                } 
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
```

All works fine, but at this point, as we well know v-show function shows some offers, while hiding the rest, not removing them from the DOM which is making pagination (five offers per page) impossible to configure, for example

show offers with speciality 1 -> html

```
offer.speciality[1]
offer.speciality[1]
offer.speciality[2] (display:none;)
offer.speciality[3] (display:none;)
offer.speciality[] (display:none;)
Pagination (1) 2 3 4 ...
```

So what approach should I choose instead od v-show to make this work? Should I remove `v-show=""` and make some kind of conditional inside `v-for`? How to make this dynamic, while `v-for` is lazy, and I'm triggering the change of `speciality` variable from the select?

Comment: instead of using a function to filter, use a computed property for the filtered list and use v-for on that.

Comment: @MatJ Thanks Mat J this seems a better approach

Comment: @MatJ Will v-for notice itself that array was changed by computed property and rerender the output or I need to trigger v-for somehow?

Comment: computed properties are reactive, it re-evaluates whenever any of the properties you use inside it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use computed property for filtered cars, here is an example for

```js
new Vue({
 el:"#app",
  data:{
   manufacturer:'',
    cars: [
        {manufacturer:"toyota", model:2012},
            {manufacturer:"ford", model:2013},
            {manufacturer:"subaro", model:2010},
            {manufacturer:"ford", model:2014},
            {manufacturer:"subaro", model:2010},
            {manufacturer:"ford", model:2016},
            {manufacturer:"dodge", model:2014},
            {manufacturer:"ford", model:2015},
            {manufacturer:"ford", model:2014}
            
          ],
    current_page:1
  },
  computed:{
   filteredCars: function(){
     var cars = []
     if(this.manufacturer == ''){
       cars = this.cars
      }
      else
      {
        cars = this.cars.filter(car => {
          if (car.manufacturer == this.manufacturer){
            return true
          }
          return false
        })
      }
      return cars.slice((this.current_page-1)*3, this.current_page*3)
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label for="">Type manufacturer</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="manufacturer">
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="car in filteredCars">{{car.manufacturer}} | {{car.model}}</li>
  </ul>
  
  <hr>
  <label for="">Page</label>
  <input type="number" v-model.number="current_page">
</div>
```

Comment: it works like a charm, you helped me a lot! I only change a little within functions (added for loop) and added `.slice()` to `v-for` instead of in computed property

Comment: Nice to hear that !